# Wrong date while converting date in php

Tags: php, mysql, date

I used the following code to convert date in php, but I am getting wrong date after the conversion. I used CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as default value in my database table.I am passing "date" variable from javascript.

Can anyone please solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

```
$date1=mysql_real_escape_string($data->date);
print_r($date1) // This is one displaying the right date.
$date=strtotime($date1);
$timedatenew=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date);
print_r($timedatenew) // This is displaying the date like "1970-01-01 01:00:00".
```

Comment: Have you set a default timezone using `date_default_timezone_set()` ?

Comment: Try date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date));

Comment: So what is the value of `$data1` or are we expected to guess that your'e using `dd/mm/yyyy` format, and a value like `13/04/2016`

Comment: @The42ndDoctor Yes, I set default timezone to date_default_timezone_set("UTC");

Comment: @ManinderpreetSingh I did that change also, but no use.

Comment: Is $date1 format in slash like d/m ??

Comment: @MarkBaker, Yes. I am using the same format dd/mm/yyyy. I am getting the date as 13/04/2016 while using print_r($date1), but not while using print_r($timedatenew)

Comment: @ManinderpreetSingh Yes.

Comment: Try date("Y-m-d",strtotime(str_replace('/', '-',  YOUR DATE ))));  it convert / to -

Comment: @ManinderpreetSingh, That's working fine. Thanks :)

Comment: Happy to help u , I posted it as ans ;)

Comment: so your problem was only for replacing / with - ? Really ?

Comment: If a date uses a `/` separator, PHP sees it as US format (`mm/dd/yyyy`); if it uses a `-` separator, then it is seen as UK/European format (`dd-mm-yyyy`).... as US (with the `/`) there is no 4th day of the 13th month, so it's an invalid date

Comment: But it works fine at my answer without any conversion fom / to - just test it and see it

Comment: @MarkBaker oh, thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @androidnation, No man. I checked but it is not working. Sorry.

Comment: So you asked something and the solution was about something else ? Great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As u said u have date in format `dd/mm/yy` try with this

```
  $timedatenew=  date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $date ))));
```

it convert / to -

Answer (score 0):

You are getting wrong date because when you use `date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date))` for converting date format then Dates in the `m/d/Y` or `d-m-Y` formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components:

if the **separator is a slash (/), then the American `m/d/Y`** is assumed; whereas if the **separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European `d-m-Y` format** is assumed. Check detail here: [php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

(above part is commented by [hjpotter92](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1190388/hjpotter92) in same this type of other question)

if you want exact right format then use DateTime object, it can format the date from any string format, it also works well with other formatter other than `-` like `/` or `.`

that means you can change date format from:

`d/m/Y` or `d-m-Y` or `d.m.Y` to your any desired format like `Y-m-d`.

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', "12/07/2019");
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');

// output: 2019-07-12
```

see below examples from the php official doc [DateTime::createFromFormat](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Example DateTime::createFromFormat()

**Object oriented style**

```
<?php
     $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('j-M-Y', '15-Feb-2009');
     echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
?>
```

**Procedural style**

```
<?php
     $date = date_create_from_format('j-M-Y', '15-Feb-2009');
     echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
?>
```

The above examples will output:

```
2009-02-15
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use that :

```
$date = '15-Feb-2009';
$date = new DateTime($date);
echo $date->format("Y-m-d");
```