# Convert dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd in php

Tags: php, date

I need to convert date format in php , But i am getting getting error

here is my code

```
 $test = new DateTime('23/09/2016');
   echo date_format($test, 'Y-m-d');
```

But i am getting error as

```
Message: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (23/09/2016) at position 0 (2): Unexpected character
```

How to resolve the issue

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36602384/wrong-date-while-converting-date-in-php/36602902#36602902

Answer (score 0):

You're not telling `DateTime` that what's your string date format. So, it's unable to create a `DateTime` object.

This should work :

```
$test = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '23/09/2016');
echo date_format($test, 'Y-m-d');
```

Read more about `createFromFormat` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

Answer (score 0):

Use [createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) instead. Like this,

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '23/09/2016');
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
```

It's throwing exception because it's unable to parse String to date with `/` in it.

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error because your code is not match with Years and Day.
If you write code below it will work.I just exchange between Years and days .

```
 $test = new DateTime('2016/09/23');
 echo date_format($test, 'Y-m-d');
```

Or you can use `createFromFormat` to format first date string then convert it in your required format.

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = "23/09/2016";
$arr = explode("/", $input);
#   mktime is a function to create timestamp
#   mktime (hour, min, sec, month, day, year)
$mktime = mktime(0,0,0,(int) $arr[1],(int)$arr[0],(int)$arr[2]);
$date1 = date ('d/m/Y', $mktime);
$date2 = date ('Y/m/d', $mktime);

echo "input: $input\ndate1: $date1\ndate2: $date2\n";
```

or you can try this one, $date2 is the final result.